# Add new contact via intent with multiple phone numbers

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I want to add a new contact using `ContactsContract.Intents.Insert`. But the problem is that I don't know how many phone numbers can be. And as I understand I can pass only three phone numbers using `PHONE`, `SECONDARY_PHONE`, `TERTIARY_PHONE` constants. Is there any way to pass more than three numbers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found a solution. It consists in using ContentValues:

```java
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    ArrayList<ContentValues> data = new ArrayList<ContentValues>();
    
    // Filling data with phone numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPhones; i++) {
        ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
        row.put(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        row.put(Phone.NUMBER, PhonesNumberList.get(i));
        // Setting the type of this phone number to be of Phone.TYPE_WORK
        row.put(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_WORK);
        data.add(row);
    }
    
    intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME, mName);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA, data);
    startActivity(contactIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend Ov3r1oad answer with email:

```
ContentValues row = new ContentValues();
row.put(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS, emailAddress);
row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK);
data.add(row);
```