# How can I add a phone number to an existing contact via Intent?

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile

I'm trying to mimic the native behaviour of adding a phone number to an existing contact. The native behaviour has the following steps:

1. Tapping on the "Add to a contact"/ "Update existing" opens the native contacts list Activity where the user has the option to choose a contact.
2. Tapping on a contact opens the native edit contact activity and adds the selected phone number as an alternative phone number field (i.e. work).

Can I achieve this using an intent?

Similarly, I'm adding a contact using an intent. Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,phoneNumber);
intent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
dialog.dismiss();
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22962365/add-new-contact-via-intent-with-multiple-phone-numbers     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278587/insert-a-new-contact-intent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert a new contact intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278587/insert-a-new-contact-intent)

Comment: i think you need to use content provider for this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179064/android-contact-info-update-with-intent

Comment: @RonTLV your solution worked. Please posted as an answer and I shall accept it. Thanks everyone for taking the time to post a potential solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the way to do it:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
i.putExtra(Insert.NAME, "TESTTEST");
i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE, "209384");
startActivity(i);
```